# Generating Conditional Summary Statistics in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

My apologies for the rather simple question, as despite having some experience with R for econometrics/regression analysis, I somehow managed to skip learning how to create basic summary statistics in R. How can I generate an output that 1) counts the number observations that that particular

For this dataframe, how can I count the different number of observations of each type for a particular column (ie: how many Ls and Rs are in column "Side")? From there how could I breakdown the count and percentage for the 'State' column if the "Side" column is equal to 'L' ( for example, when 'Side' is equal to 'L', what percent of the time is it green or red or blue?

```
Side   State    Color    Type            
L       O       Green     B
R       C       Red       Q
R       O       Red       C
R       O       Blue      L
L       C       Green     B
L       C       Yellow    C
```

Here is the type of output I'm looking for:

```
Side  Count    %
L     13      38%
R     21      68%
```

For Side=L

```
Color  Count    %
Green  4        31
Red    7        54
Blue   1        8
Yellow 1        8
```

For Side=R

```
Color  Count    %
Green  11       52
Red    4        19
Blue   2        10
Yellow 4        19
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `count` to count the frequencies and `prop.table` to count the ratio.

For each `Side` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  count(Side, name = 'Count') %>%
  mutate(Perc = prop.table(Count) * 100)
```

For the `color` in each `Side` :

```
df %>%
  count(Side, Color, name = 'Count') %>%
  group_by(Side) %>%
  mutate(Perc = prop.table(Count) * 100)
```

Comment: Ronak, as always you are amazing. What if I wanted to take the analysis a step further--ie: how could I show the summary statistics for color as you did if "Side"=L and 'State'=0. In other words, how can I show the exact same thing if I add another condition.

Comment: @rogues77 In that case, you can add `group_by` `Color` instead of `group_by` `Side`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `summarise` with `group_by`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(Side) %>% 
    summarise(Count  = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
    mutate(Perc = 100 * Count/sum(Count))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  Side  Count  Perc
#  <chr> <int> <dbl>
#1 L         3    50
#2 R         3    50
```

---

For the second case

```
df %>% 
   group_by(Side, Color) %>%
   summarise(Count  = n(), .groups = 'drop_last') %>% 
   mutate(Perc = 100 * Count/sum(Count))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   Side [2]
#  Side  Color  Count  Perc
#  <chr> <chr>  <int> <dbl>
#1 L     Green      2  66.7
#2 L     Yellow     1  33.3
#3 R     Blue       1  33.3
#4 R     Red        2  66.7
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Side = c("L", "R", "R", "R", "L", "L"), State = c("O", 
"C", "O", "O", "C", "C"), Color = c("Green", "Red", "Red", "Blue", 
"Green", "Yellow"), Type = c("B", "Q", "C", "L", "B", "C")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```